# Why is fullscreen image slider still slow?

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm trying to swipe through gallery images by using a pager adapter and glide to load the images. It is working but it could be faster. I'd like to have it as fast as android's gallery app.

I've tried many glide options. It gets as fast as i want if i set .override(600,200) but that is not an appropriate solution of course. I tried to get the ImageView size with a treeObserver for the first image to scale all  following ones to the appropriate size. But that doesn't make it really faster unfortunately.

So why is it still slow and what can i do to make it faster?

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container,final int position) {            
        ImageView imgView;   
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,false);

        imgView = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.img_view);

        Glide.with(_activity).load(_imagePaths.get(position))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .dontAnimate()
                //.override(600, 200) //this is really fast, but not a solution for best quality!!
                .into(imgView);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

        return viewLayout;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use picasso and resize image according to screen height and width. Right now you are loading large image in page adapter thats why its taking time to load image on imageview while swipe view pager.

```
 Picasso.with(this)
                .load("your image path")
                .resize(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight())
                .into(imageview);
```

Comment: So you' re saying loading large image into pager adapter by using picasso will be faster? I should do it exactly like i did but should picasso instead? I thought glide is faster.

Comment: Picasso and glide both are same but you need to resize image according to screen size, some images are larger then screen resolution and its slow app performance.

Comment: well, as i wrote i tried to get the imageView size with a tree-observer (getting width and height when imageView is actually drawn) and scaled the images with glide by .override(width,height). But that was still not fast enough. But i' ll give your code with windowManager a try (with both glide and picasso). thank you so far!

Comment: Not making it faster unfortunately. Tried Picasso too, way slower than glide.